# Computing statistics using Python scripting

Tags: arcpy, statistics

I'm new to Python but I've heard is a good way to automate tasks. I have thousands of point shapefiles and need to extract the maximum value of each one and put them in a new table.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick simple way to do this:

```
list = [shapefile, shapefile] #enter in all of your shapefiles here in a list. You can do this with python as well.
for layer in list:
     arcpy.Statistics_analysis (layer, "out_table.dbf", [["NORTHING", "MAX"]])
```

---

```
list = ListFeatureClasses ("#", "Point", "C:/Database_Location")
for layer in list:
     arcpy.Statistics_analysis (layer, "out_table.dbf", [["NORTHING", "MAX"]])
```

Answer (score 6):

beside @Cody Brown **Statistics_analysis**, you can use **max** function to find maximum value of your feature.

```
import arcpy

workspace = "C:\Data\Test\test.shp"
recs = arcpy.SearchCursor(workspace)

ary = []

for rec in recs:
   val = rec.getValue('Distance')
   ary.append(val)

print max(ary)
```